# How to add columns to the kendo ui grid dynamically

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I have rendered grid with simple data and now I want to add an extra column to the existing grid How can do this. Can any one help me in this.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the columns as hidden upfront and reveal them when needed?

Comment: Either have the column created and hidden and then show it or you need to create a new Grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the mvc wrappers the. You can template a column like this

```
 Column.template(@< text >< /text >).clienttemplate({what ever you want adding in here as the template eg "< p >I am a special column< /p >"});
```

Your grid code would help to figure out what you actually need but I hope this helps.

Comment: This fails for aspnet core kendo. Can you please help with that?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by fetching all columns at the initial load and I have rendered all the columns in the grid and I am using hideColumn and showColumn of grid methods.